# AngularJs - Select tag don't show the selected value in the select box

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown which gets the value from AngularJs using **ng-option**  with the following code:

```
<select ng-model="selectedShelf"
        ng-change="shelfChangedValue(selectedShelf)"
        ng-options="shelf as shelf.name for shelf in shelfs">
</select>

<p>Selected shelf: {{selectedShelfName}}</p>
```

this is the Angularjs Code:

```
     angular.forEach(shelfData, function(item) {
      $scope.shelfs.push({
      id: item.id,
      name: item.name
    });          
      $scope.shelfChangedValue=function(item){
          $scope.selectedShelf="";
          $scope.selectedShelf=item.id;
          $scope.selectedShelfName=item.name;
          $scope.selectedModel = "";
          $scope.selectedModelName="";
          $scope.disabled=false;
```

The problem is that, when I choose one of the values, the value is not shown in the box and  the box of the dropdown remains empty, the only why to show the selected value is to use `<p>Selected shelf: {{selectedShelfName}}</p>`
instead the second select works as it should.

the problem is not

tag, the problem is with the dropdown, when i select one option, the box of the dropdown remains empty

I don't know what is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your `selfChangeValue` function is very weird. I suggest you a simpler approach:

The select directly select id (and not the whole object):

```
<select ng-model="selectedShelf"
        ng-change="shelfChangedValue(selectedShelf)"
        ng-options="shelf.id as shelf.name for shelf in shelfs">
</select>
```

So `selectedShelf` contains a shelf ID: `{{selectedShelf}}`.

The `shelfChangedValue` function now **only** initialize `selectedShelfName`:

```
$scope.shelfChangedValue = function(item) {
     $scope.selectedShelfName = item.name;
     /* Other treatments you add in your code */
     $scope.selectedModel = "";
     $scope.selectedModelName = "";
     $scope.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I guess you didn't read well my question! the problem is not <p> tag, the problem is with the dropdown, when i select one option, the box of the dropdown remains empty